# how to clone forms in javascript preserving event bindings

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, forms, clone

I am about to clone a part of form which has some actions bound to `click` events. I want to change all occurences of word `TEMPLATE` in attributes to `'n_'+ID`. I want to abstract from structure of cloned part - It would be one `TEMPLATE` or 10. 
I tried to something like this but the bindings are lost:

```
insert = function(){
    var old = $('#TEMPLATE');
    var copy = old.clone(true); 
    var html = old.html().replace(/TEMPLATE/g,'n'+next_ID);
    old.html(html);
    old.attr('id','n'+next_ID);
    old.show('fast');
    old.after(copy);
    next_ID++;
}
```

Is there any way to do it easily without knowing anything about the structure of the copied element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You would have to re-add handlers each time.

If you really want to avoid this, use event delegation ([`delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) or [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/)) to attach your event handlers. That way they are not associated with particular node objects, but only the placement of elements, whether they match a selector, at event firing time.

```
$(myform).delegate('.dosomething', 'click', function() {
    // handle clicks on any .dosomething in the form now or added later
});
```

(And try to avoid text processing over the `html()`/`innerHTML`. This is unreliable. It's better to iterate over objects whose names or classes you want to change doing it with `attr`.)